# Android Studio Layout Editor ConstraintLayout greyed out in dynamic modules

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-constraintlayout, android-module

I have been using on demand dynamic modules in by app for a few years now, and in the past this issue did not happen. I noticed this recently as I wanted to work on my dynamic module that the layout editor did not render the `ConstraintLayout`. The interesting part is that this is only an issue in the Android Studio layout editor, as on the device everything works fine.

Please note that I have included the implementation
`api 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'` in the main `.app` module, but not in the dynamic module. As mentioned above, this works on the device but is not recognized by the layout editor. This used to work correctly with the Layout Editor in the past.

A work around to this problem is to add the `api 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'` to each dynamic module, however I believe this approach is unnecessary as this library is already included in the main `.app` module. Additionally, would there be any app size implications by this implementation being used multiple times?

In conclusion, I would like to ask if this is the expected behaviour of the the Android Studio layout editor, and if that is the case, what is the best way to solve this problem? Or, is this a bug with Android Studio that needs to be reported, as this issue did not occur in the past?